# Memory issue while checking image size

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the size of the images picked via UIImagePicker

here is the code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage 
    var imgData: NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 1)!)
    var imageSize: Int = imgData.length
    print("size of image in KB: %f ", Double(imageSize) / 1024.0)
}
```

This throws an error:

> Message from Debugger: Terminated due to Memory issue.

Note: The image file size was around 75 MB on disk. It is working fine for lower size images.

Comment: You already have the image, and then you make a whole _new_ version of that image by taking its JPEG representation, and you hold _that_ in memory too, and then you take an NSData from _that_ and you hold _that_ in memory, and you are surprised when you run out of memory? What exactly is the question anyway? What do you ultimately even want to _do_?

Comment: see i want to show images to user basically only if it is less than 30 mb of size. so i have to check the size. I am understanding this issue but unable to find solution.

Comment: One thing I'm saying is: You _have_ the image. So you can check its size. You don't need to check the size of something _else_, which is just what you are doing. But I am also saying: You are _never_ going to "show" the user a 30 MB image. That would be silly. The screen can't hold such an image! You should always load a version of the image no larger than what you need for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FileManager` to check the file size (and other attributes). To get the URL of selected image, there is a `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key. It gives you the URL of the file and you can pass it to the FileManager, like following:

```
if let imgURL : URL = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? URL,
let attribs = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: imgURL.path) {
    let size = attribs[FileAttributeKey.size]
    print(size)
}
```